# Faced module not found after I installed bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to React and was learning how to use bootstrap in React but after installation I faced "Module not found: Can't resolve './bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' in 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\weather app\weather-app\src'". Here is my code:

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import "./bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import SearchBox from "./Containers/SearchBox/SearchBox";
import Header from "./Components/Header/Header";
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Fragment>
        <Header title={"WeatherMap"} />
        <SearchBox />
      </Fragment>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "weather-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: please share your folder structure with a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps, you can check this [link](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction)

The best way to consume React-Bootstrap is via the npm package which you can install with npm (or yarn if you prefer).

If you plan on customizing the Bootstrap Sass files, or don't want to use a CDN for the stylesheet, it may be helpful to install vanilla Bootstrap as well.

```
npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap
```

Because React-Bootstrap doesn't depend on a very precise version of Bootstrap, we don't ship with any included CSS. However, some stylesheet is required to use these components.

{/* The following line can be included in your src/index.js or App.js file*/}

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

I think its the dot before your import, remove dot then try

Answer (score 0):

After a long research, it turned out that I need to remove ./ when importing bootstrap. So replace import `'./bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';` with `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`